# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000

Tags: javascript, express, postman

estoy tratando de probar con Postman una api que estoy desarrollando, y Postman me devuelve el siguiente error

`>Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000.`

A su vez en Powershell, me devuelve:

```
[nodemon] 2.0.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
(node:7516) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
New app listening at http://localhost:3000
Connected successfully to server ::
```

Alguien sabe como solucionar? gracias!!

Comment: Al parecer se esta ejecutando un proceso | aplicacion | etc, en el puerto 3000 donde estas tratando de realizar el request con postman. Asegúrate que no haya ningún proceso bloqueando ese puerto y prueba otra vez